# Is there historical evidence whether or not FAR §21.9 applies to owner-manufactured avionics?

Tags: faa-regulations, aircraft-maintenance, avionics

Looking at an [explanation of `§21.9`](https://www.aviationpros.com/home/article/10387511/owner-produced-parts-how-they-affect-maintenance) (formerly `§21.303(b)2`), it seems very straightforward for an owner to produce a part for an airplane, so long as it meets req'd airworthiness specs. However, judging from the article it seems like the regulation intent was more about mechanical parts, such as an antenna shelf or maintenance parts for orphaned planes.

So what if I made some basic avionics of my own design, e.g. a soaring computer of my own design or an engine monitor? Is there any case law or legal interpretations which give guidance here?

Comment: I think it comes down to whether or not the intended use is one that requires a TSO compliant part, like for IFR use etc. If not, I don't think it matters who makes it.

Comment: @JohnK I'm not 100% positive, but I thought that there is no requirement that avionics be TSOd, beyond the transponder and ADSB (and maybe another such or sundry).

Comment: Yeah I think so. There's nothing stopping you from flying VFR using a handheld. And for navigating, I used a tablet for a while but now I just use my phone with Naviator installed on it for flying to breakfast fly ins and such lol.

Comment: Are you asking about certified aircraft, or homebuilt experimental?

Comment: @MichaelHall Certified. Would this even apply to experimental?

Comment: @JohnK I love my tablet for navigating! However, I think that those examples would fall under the umbrella of non-permanent installations, whereas 21.9 feels more like it's for permanently installed stuff. So could I make my own SDR-based NAV radios which slot into the KX175 tray, my own engine monitor with bespoke UI, etc...?

Comment: I'm just puzzled why you think you might be allowed to install home made avionics in certified aircraft.

Comment: @MichaelHall Read FAR 21.9. Owners are allowed to manufacture their own parts to "maintain or alter" their airplanes. That legality doesn't compel an A&P to sign it off, though. Thus why I'm looking for evidence either way on avionics, which would qualify as "alter".

Comment: Building on that point, there seems to be a lack of evidence that the FAA even requires TSO'd avionics (beyond the xponder/ADSB stuff) for Pt. 91 operations. It's all quite confusing when you dive into it.

Comment: Can you steer me to a specific subsection that backs your assertion? The way I read the section it’s about applying to alter the type certificate. (Which if I understand correctly, you’d have to do.) Simply allowing homebuilt parts to be added to a certified design doesn’t fit anything I know about the FAA.

Comment: @MichaelHall https://www.aviationpros.com/home/article/10387511/owner-produced-parts-how-they-affect-maintenance is the link from the question. Let me know if that explanation isn't satisfactory and I'll look for others.

Comment: I would think that it would be OK from the FAA's point of view for you to install a piece of avionics equipment on your own aircraft as long as it is not one of the items listed in your aircraft's type certificate datasheet. Whether it is a good idea depends on what it is, what you use for, and what your insurance will think about it. You might be giving them the perfect excuse to deny a claim for an incident or accident.